# Delete elements from JSON based on IDs

Tags: javascript, json

I have got two JavaScript arrays and need to exclude based on IDs and timestamp.

```
var str = [{"id":"5","name":"Test 1","ends":"2020-04-05 10:00"},{"id":"6","name":"Test 2","ends":"2020-03-29 12:33"},{"id":"8","name":"Test 3","ends":"2020-08-29 12:33"}];

var exclude = [5,8];
```

So I expect to filter by date (remove all which are older than NOW) and remove those which IDs in **exclude** array.

I really don't know how to do it. Please help as I am just beginning to learn JavaScript.

Thank you.

Comment: Those are not "JSON strings", they're arrays.

Comment: Thank you @Pointy I just edited my question.

Comment: what you've tried so far ?

Comment: @CodeManiac I tried this: var filtered = str.filter(function(item) { 
   return item.id !== exclude;  
});

Comment: Again, they're not "JSON arrays". They're JavaScript arrays. JSON is a serialization scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify @Thalaivar's answer to take into account the time of the date

```
var str = [
  {"id":"5","name":"Test 1","ends":"2020-05-07 10:00"},
  {"id":"6","name":"Test 2","ends":"2020-05-07 09:55"},
  {"id":"8","name":"Test 3","ends":"2020-08-29 12:33"}
];

var exclude = [5,8];

var filterDate = str.filter(e => {
   var todayInTime = new Date().getTime();
   var recordDateInTime = new Date(e.ends).getTime();
   return (recordDateInTime > todayInTime && exclude.indexOf(Number(e.id)) === -1)
})

console.log("filterDate", filterDate);
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/quethzel/64bgexsd/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot Thalaivar and @QuethzelDíaz

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like below to get the result:

```
var str = [{"id":"5","name":"Test 1","ends":"2020-05-07 10:00"},{"id":"6","name":"Test 2","ends":"2020-03-29 12:33"},{"id":"8","name":"Test 3","ends":"2020-08-29 12:33"}];
var exclude = [5,8];
var today = new Date().getTime(); 

var filterDate = str.filter(function(el){
   var otherDate = new Date(el.ends).getTime();
   return !Object.keys(el).some(k => 
       el['id'].toLowerCase().includes(exclude))
           && (otherDate > today)     
   })

   console.log("filterDate", filterDate);
```

**A fiddle to help you with:**

https://jsfiddle.net/8hLqpsd5/2/

Comment: Thank you @Thalaivar The filterDate is still having data with ID 5. But it should be excluded as it is in the array.

Comment: Probably it would be more efficient to check the ID before the date, to save the work of building the Date instances. Also of course the "today" date could be built outside the function.

Comment: Still returns  {id: "5", name: "Test 1", ends: "2020-05-07 10:00"}

Comment: Thank you very much @Thalaivar

Comment: @qqruza: That's fine, take care and stay safe brother.